# Heroku logs mistake unexpected token same code as in the mooc

Tags: json, facebook-chatbot

I made a mooc on udemy regarding chatbots. Unfortunately, I failed at the point where I wanted the chatbot to send me data via mail.

What does this log expression tells me? What might be the mistake here?

[image]

Where can I search for the mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot a `)` at line 35, the simple syntaxt for a `if` is:

```
if (condition) {

 // do something

} else {

 // or anything else

}
```

You should learn about `if` statement, here an example : https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp

Basically, a `SyntaxError` shows to you the line where the error happened, here `/app/app.js:35`, so the error is in your file `app.js` at line `:35`.
Here more clarification: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-syntax-and-code-structure-in-javascript

It's possible that you have an other error yet, but we only see the end of it in your screenshot..